# AWSSNS (Amazon Push notification) , App crash

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, amazon-sns

I wanted to implement snspush notification service provided by amazon.
I install pod for that.
In podfile I write:

```rb
pod 'AWSSNS'
```

after that I execute `pod install`.

**Then I implement code like this:**

```c
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *messageCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    messageCategory.identifier = @"ShareAction";
    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *notificationAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    notificationAction.identifier = @"ShareAction";
    notificationAction.title = @"Share";
    notificationAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground;
    notificationAction.authenticationRequired = YES;
    notificationAction.destructive = NO;
    [messageCategory setActions:@[notificationAction] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:messageCategory];

    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:categories];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken{
    NSString *deviceTokenString = [[[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"deviceTokenString: %@", deviceTokenString);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:deviceTokenString forKey:@"deviceToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    AWSSNS *sns = [AWSSNS defaultSNS];
    AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput *request = [AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput new];
    request.token = deviceTokenString;
    request.platformApplicationArn = SNSPlatformApplicationArn;
    [[sns createPlatformEndpoint:request] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
        if (task.error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",task.error);
        } else {
            AWSSNSCreateEndpointResponse *createEndPointResponse = task.result;
            NSLog(@"endpointArn: %@",createEndPointResponse);
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:createEndPointResponse.endpointArn forKey:@"endpointArn"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }

        return nil;
    }];
}
```

When I run app, There is crash with following log:

> **** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The service configuration is `nil`. You need to configure `Info.plist` or set `defaultServiceConfiguration` before using this method.'*

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:categories];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
}
```

Comment: Its same ,Print log as             Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The service configuration is nil. You need to configure Info.plist or set defaultServiceConfiguration before using this method.'